# aggrid: No data available to be charted

Tags: ag-grid

I have a newbie question on ag-grid enterprise (using v23.0.0). When I create a simple grid, and then do these user actions:

1. Right click on a numeric cell
2. Choose Chart Range, Column, Grouped (actually, none of the charting options work...)

I get `No data available to be charted.`

This works fine in the demo (`https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php`), but not in my application. What do I need to do to get the data to be displayed in the chart?

I am using the Flask web application framework to host my Python code. Here is my HTML/JavaScript code:

agpoc.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='ag-grid-enterprise.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='agpoc.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="salesGrid" style="height: 200px; width:500px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

agpoc.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#salesGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});

var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "brand", field: "brand"},
    {headerName: "sales", field: "sales", type: "numericColumn"}
];
var rowData = [
    {"brand": "Brand X", "sales": "270.12"},
    {"brand": "Brand Y", "sales": "400.89"}
];

var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData,
  enableCharts: true,
  enableRangeSelection: true,
};
```

I have debugged this and it appears that the following code within `ag-grid-enterprise.js`:

`ChartDataModel.prototype.getSelectedValueColState()`

returns an empty list. I do not understand what `example.js` is doing that I am not doing wrt this behavior.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thank you

Comment: Try it with numerical data instead. `"sales": 270.12`.

Comment: Nice, that worked! Thank you @thirtydot.

Comment: @thirtydot - please post your comment as an answer, so others may benefit from it :)

Comment: @EliranMalka: I don't really write answers here anymore, I'm not happy with Stack Exchange. You can write a full answer yourself.

Comment: that's too bad... found any good alternatives yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

So this can be a little confusing. In your particular example it's as your `sales` are `strings` and not `numbers`.

For things to work by default you must make sure that for each row there is a numerical value available. Having an `undefined` or `null` for example will cause the `no data available issue`.

To get around this, you need to define a `chartDataType` on the colDef of the particular column you're interested in.

Here is an example where I prepend a row with `age` as `null` yet it still works due to defining the `chartDataType` as `series`

https://plnkr.co/edit/nyzxLY5tntyURkK3

Edit*
This looks like a bug soon to be fixed:

```
If chartDataType in the column definition is not provided, AG Grid infers whether the data is numeric (for plotting as a series values), or not (for plotting as category values) based on the first row in the column. If the first row in this column doesn't contain a numeric value, it's treated as a category value which cannot be charted, as described here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/integrated-charts-range-chart/#inferred-by-the-grid

This is why please set chartDataType='series' on columns you want to chart in order to avoid cases where there's a null/undefined value in the first row, which infers the column as a category column and prevents it from charting.
```

The answer still applies for now.